Eclipse PHP built in server not finding project files
I installed Eclipse with PDT. I installed PHP 8.3 with chocolatery. I setup a built in server inside eclipse to run PHP. I added my PHP project folder as a COnfigured resource in the server. I try to run my PHP project. But i get 404 not found. It seems like it just cant get the source files and i dont know why. I add images of my configuration. If something is missing, tell me and ill add.
I also tested PHPStorm free trial. And there its just press run and it works. THe way i would like things to be in eclipse, since phpstorm is expencive.

[Wed Sep  4 08:41:21 2024] PHP 8.3.11 Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:8080) started
[Wed Sep  4 08:41:22 2024] 127.0.0.1:49236 Accepted
[Wed Sep  4 08:41:22 2024] 127.0.0.1:49236 [404]: GET / - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 08:41:22 2024] 127.0.0.1:49236 Closing
[Wed Sep  4 08:41:23 2024] 127.0.0.1:49252 Accepted
[Wed Sep  4 08:41:23 2024] 127.0.0.1:49252 [404]: GET /Learning/hello.php - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 08:41:23 2024] 127.0.0.1:49252 Closing
[Wed Sep  4 08:41:23 2024] 127.0.0.1:49253 Accepted
[Wed Sep  4 08:41:23 2024] 127.0.0.1:49253 [404]: GET /favicon.ico - No such file or directory
[Wed Sep  4 08:41:23 2024] 127.0.0.1:49253 Closing

Also added server config inside the eclipse. maybe that helps. Maybe document root is wrong, but i dont know what sohuld be right one.

Can people please stop voting to close this kind of stuff as "not about programming" - I see there's one such vote here already. It's absolutely about programming. If anyone needs a reminder, What topics can I ask about here? says: "if your question generally covers…software tools commonly used by programmers...then you’re in the right place" . I think closing questions which are clearly about getting a programming IDE set up correctly is enforcing an excessively narrow view of a "programming question", and isn't in the spirit of the site rules.

Are you letting the Project "build"?

define build? I press run. And then thats that. I get 404 and nothing more will happen.

@nitind As much as i can see. it seems like when i press run, the build process is instantly terminated. And i dont know why.

From the Project menu. It's often when deployment to that staging area would be performed. Either the Project menu will show that Automatic builds are enabled, or you need to trigger one manually, if the selected project has any defined.

Can you add a screenshot of the Builder property page for the project (right-click on the project and open its Properties dialog)?

@nitind added image

I guess you need to check to see if the Error Log view has anything mentioning the Script Builder. I'm not really sure how the PHP workflow is supposed to go, otherwise I could be more specific.

@nitind "Port 8579 required by PHP Built-in Server at localhost is already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s)."
It automatically starts the server on that port when i pres runn on my project. So i dont know what its whinign about.

@nitind added console log also. Error log is now empty and nothing appears there. It seems to be that server is just not picking up the project folder to get the sources.

same error. its not issue of port, but issue of not finding project f iles

Except that if the port is already in use, the PHP server you're trying to launch isn't the one responding to your request, whatever was already running is.

if server is not running then ther is no page at all. running the app automatically starts the server, if there is something else. then i dont know what it might be

@nitind Tested port. Port is only in use when i run my server. And when i close it the port is no longer in use. So it cant be port issue, unless eclipse without my knowledge opens another server to serve the files.
